# Generate hash for each new document in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I am using SharePoint server 2013

1. I would like to create an event receiver on a document library, and inside this event receiver I would like to generate an hash for example an MD5 hash.
2. In the event receiver I would like to add this generated MD5 hashs the column "LatestHashCode" of the document list item.

When I download the document to my local machine and unmodify it, will it have the same MD5 hashs? Or is the MD5 hash modified because of step 2?

The target is to share the (document hyperlink + md5 hash) to external partners. The external partners can always check at a later phase if the document is stil original or modified.

Comment: I would *assume* that if you used SPListItem.SystemUpdate (false) in step two you would be okay. The only tricky bit would be if MS Docs actually embed the server properties in the document or if the application loads them at run-time. You may just have to try it to find out...